# Powershell Invoke-Command passing environment variables

Tags: powershell, invoke-command

I wish to use Invoke-Command passing environment variables from the calling machine to the server where Invoke-Command is being executed.

I want this to work:

```
Invoke-Command -ComputerName MyServer-ScriptBlock {
    $env:VAR=$using:env:USERNAME
    Write-Host $env:VAR
}
```

But the output for this command is empty.  If I do not use the $using scope modifier, and just assign the variable directly I get the expected output ("VAR").

```
Invoke-Command -ComputerName MyServer -ScriptBlock {
   $env:VAR="VAR"
   Write-Host $env:VAR
}
```

So, can I use $using with environment variables?  If not, is there an easy way to pass environment variables over to the remote computer where Invoke-Command is running?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One option would be to assign the environment variable to a standard variable before invoking:

```
$username = $env:USERNAME

Invoke-Command -ComputerName MyServer-ScriptBlock {
    $env:VAR=$using:userName
    Write-Host $env:VAR
}
```

Note that assigning environment variables like this (`$env:VAR=<value>`) won't persist once your session ends.  Use the [Environment.SetEnvironmentVariable()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.environment.setenvironmentvariable(v=vs.110).aspx) method to do that.

Comment: This seems about the easiest way to do it.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I think you could use `-ArgumentList`. See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/invoke-command?view=powershell-6

```
Invoke-Command -ComputerName MyServer -ArgumentList $env:USERNAME -ScriptBlock {
    Param ($x)

    Write-Host $x
}
```

Answer (score 1):

**Update**: The **bug** described below has been **fixed in v7.3**.

---

The existing answers show helpful *workarounds*.

**It looks like you've hit a *bug***, present up to PowerShell 7.2.x:

The **`$using:` scope** - which is **required for accessing variable values from the caller's scope in all *out-of-runspace* executions** (see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60012780/45375)) - ***should* also support namespace variable notation** (see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55036515/45375)).

Thus, you *should* be able to pass a namespace-notation variable reference such as `$env:USERNAME` as `$using:env:USERNAME`:

- indeed you *can* in the context of *jobs* (child-process-based background jobs started with [`Start-Job`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/start-job) and thread-based jobs started with [`Start-ThreadJob`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/threadjob/start-threadjob)); e.g.:

  ```
  $env:FOO = 'bar'
  # Outputs 'bar', as expected.
  Start-Job { $using:env:FOO } | Receive-Job -Wait -AutoRemoveJob
  ```
- but, **as of PowerShell 7.1, that doesn't work with PowerShell [*remoting*](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/threadjob/start-threadjob), such as [`Invoke-Command`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/invoke-command) `-ComputerName`**, as in your case.

The potential bug has been reported in [GitHub issue #16019](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/16019).