# What type of object is $<drivename>: (such as `$code:`) in Powershell?

Tags: powershell, namespaces, powershell-v5.1, new-psdrive

I was using tab autocompletion for a variable name in Powershell 5.1 today and noticed that one of the choices was the name of a PSDrive. The drive name is `docs` and I wanted to expand is called `$document_name`. When I typed `$do<tab>`, the shell did indeed expand what I had typed to `$document_name` but for some reason, I typed `<tab>` a second time and that's when the expanded text changed to `$docs:`.

I explored further and found that this type of variable exists for each of my PSDrives, or at least tab expansion suggests that it does.

More formally, for every PSDrive *PSD*, tab expansion believes that `$PSD:` is a valid thing.

My question is simple: what the heck are these? Here are some observations I've made so far:

- These names are prefixed with `$`, so they look like PS variables. For the rest of this discussion (and in the earlier discussion above), I will assume they are variables and refer to them as such.
- Although they appear to be variables, they are not listed in the `Variable:` PSDrive like most variables. In this way, it behaves like the `$env` "variable," which also is not listed in `Variable:`. I have a feeling if I could find documentation about `$env`, then I'd understand these objects also.
- In some ways, they behave like pointers to filesystem objects. For example, if there is a file name `readme.txt` containing the text "Hello, world!" on a PSDrive named `code`, then all of the following are possible interactions with Powershell.

Fetch the contents of the file.

```
λ  ${code:\readme.txt}
Hello, world!
```

Just to prove that the type of the above result is `String`:

```
λ  ${code:\readme.txt} | % { $_.GetType().Name }
String
```

Trying to use this as a reference to the PSDrive doesn't work well for many operations, such as `cd`:

```
C:\
λ  cd ${code:}
At line:1 char:4
+ cd ${code:}
+    ~~~~~~~~
Variable reference is not valid. The variable name is missing.
    + CategoryInfo          : ParserError: (:) [], ParentContainsErrorRecordException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : InvalidBracedVariableReference
```

I could go on, but I'm stumped. If I pass `$code:` (or `$env:`, for that matter) to `Get-Member`, I get an error saying `Variable reference is not valid`.

So just what the heck are "variables" like `$env` and `$<PSDrive>:` (such as `$code:`)? Are they expressions? Built-in expressions? Some kind of object? Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

What you're seeing is ***namespace variable notation***, which is a **variable-based way to access the content of items in PowerShell drives** whose underlying [provider](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Providers) implements content-based access (i.e., implements the [`IContentCmdletProvider`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/System.Management.Automation.Provider.IContentCmdletProvider) interface).

**Terminology and documentation note**:

- As of this writing, the docs *briefly* explain namespace variable notation in the conceptual [about_Scopes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Scopes#scope-modifiers) help topic, albeit *without using that term* and, somewhat confusingly, discuss it in the context of ***scope modifiers***; while *namespace qualifiers* (such as `$env:`) are unrelated to scope modifiers (such as `$script:`), they use the same basic *syntax* form, however.<sup>[1]</sup>

The general **syntax** is:

```bash
${<drive>:<path>}       # same as: Get-Content <drive>:<path>

${<drive>:<path>} = ... # same as: Set-Content <drive>:<path> -Value ...
```

The enclosing `{...}` aren't necessary if both the `<drive>` name and the `<path>` can syntactically serve as a variable name; e.g.:

```bash
$env:HOME  # no {...} needed

${env:ProgramFiles(x86)} # {...} needed due to "(" and ")"
```

In practice, as of Windows PowerShell v5.1, **the following in-box drive providers support namespace variable notation**:

- Environment (drive `Env:`)
- Function (drive `Function:`)
- Alias (drive `Alias:`)
- FileSystem (drives `C:`, ...)
- Variable (drive `Variable:`) - though virtually pointless, given that omitting the drive part accesses variables by default (e.g., `$variable:HOME` is the same as just `$HOME`).

Of these, the `Env:` drive is by far the most frequently used with namespace variable notation, even though most users aren't aware of what underlies an environment-variable references such as `$env:HOME`.

On occasion you see it used with a filesystem drive - e.g., `${c:\foo\file.txt}` - but the fact that you can only use *literal* paths and that you cannot control the character encoding limits its usefulness.

It allows interesting uses, however; e.g.:

```bash
PS> $alias:foreach  # Get the definition of alias 'foreach'
ForEach-Object

PS> $function:prompt # Get the body of the 'prompt' function
"PS $($executionContext.SessionState.Path.CurrentLocation)$('>' * ($nestedPromptLevel + 1)) ";
# .Link
# https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=225750
# .ExternalHelp System.Management.Automation.dll-help.xml

# Define a function foo that echoes 'hi' and invoke it.
PS> $function:foo = { 'hi' }; foo
hi
```

Note:

- Because `${<drive>:<path>}` and `${<drive>:<path>} = <value>` are equivalent to 
  `Get-Content -Path <drive>:<path>` and `Set-Content -Path <drive>:<path> <value>`, **paths are interpreted as *wildcard expressions*** (because that's what `-Path` does, as opposed to `-LiteralPath`), which can cause problems with paths that *look like* wildcards - see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55344037/45375) for an example and a workaround.

---

<sup>[1] Previously, the feature wasn't documented at all; [GitHub docs issue #3343](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/PowerShell-Docs/issues/3343) led to the current documentation, albeit not in the way that said issue proposed.</sup>

Answer (score 1):

`$env` is the Windows environment variables, the same as what you get when you do `SET` in a command prompt. There are a few that are PS-specific.

The variable is providing access to the Environment Provider. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_environment_variables?view=powershell-6

There are a bunch of other Providers that are described here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_providers?view=powershell-6

As it says in the doco:

> The model for data presentation is a file system drive. To use data
>   that the provider exposes, you view it, move through it, and change it
>   as though it were data on a hard drive. Therefore, the most important
>   information about a provider is the name of the drive that it
>   supports.