# How to assign and reference environment variables containing square brackets in Powershell

Tags: powershell, syntax, namespaces, environment-variables

When the PSDrive is not specified, the following works:

```
${[foo]}="bar"
echo ${[foo]}
```

But the following does not work

```
$env:${[foo]}="bar"
At line:1 char:1 
+ $env:${[foo]}="bar"
+ ~~~~~
Variable reference is not valid. ':' was not followed by a valid variable name character. Consider using ${} to delimit the name.
At line:1 char:6
+ $env:${[foo]}="bar"
+      ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
Unexpected token '${[foo]}="bar"' in expression or statement.
    + CategoryInfo          : ParserError: (:) [], ParentContainsErrorRecordException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : InvalidVariableReferenceWithDrive
```

```
${env:[foo]}="bar"
Cannot find path 'env:[foo]' because it does not exist. 
At line:1 char:1
+ ${env:[foo]}="bar"
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (env:[foo]:String) [], ItemNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : PathNotFound
```

The following works, though I am curious if there's short hand syntax for it:

```
Set-Item -LiteralPath env:${[foo]} -Value "bar"
Get-Item -LiteralPath env:${[foo]} | % {$_.Value}
```

However the following does not work:

```
Set-Item -LiteralPath env:${[foo]2} -Value "bar"
Set-Item : Cannot process argument because the value of argument "name" is null. Change the value of argument "name" to a non-null value.      
At line:1 char:1
+ Set-Item -LiteralPath env:${[foo]2} -Value "bar"
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (:String) [Set-Item], PSArgumentNullException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : SetItemNullName,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.SetItemCommand
```

Comment: Great question; as an aside: `Get-Item -LiteralPath env:${[foo]}` and `Set-Item -LiteralPath env:${[foo]} -Value "bar"` do not work either, or at least won't work they way you expect, due to up-front string expansion.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

<sup>Written as of PowerShell Core 6.2.0</sup>

The reason is that PowerShell treats the following:

```sh
${<drive>:<name>}
```

as if you had specified:

```sh
Get-Content -Path <drive>:<name>  # or, with assignment, Set-Content -Path ...
```

This notation - though often used with the `Env:` drive (e.g., `$env:Path`) -  is little-known as a *general paradigm* named ***namespace variable notation***, which is explained in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55036515/45375).

**The problem is the use of `-Path` rather than `-LiteralPath`**, because `-Path` **interprets its argument as a *wildcard expression***.

Therefore, the `[foo]` in `${env:[foo]}` - rather than being used as-is - is interpreted as a wildcard expression that matches a *single* character that is either `f` or `o` (`[foo]` is a character set or range (`[...]`) that matches any one of the (distinct) characters inside - see [about_Wildcards](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_wildcards)).

On *assigning* to `${env:[foo]}`, the logic of `Set-Content -Path` requires that a wildcard-based path resolve to *something existing*, even though you're generally *not* required to explicitly create environment variables; e.g., `${env:NoSuchVarExistsYet} = 'new'` works just fine.

---

**Workaround**:

**Use *double*(!)-`` ` ``-escaping of the wildcard metacharacters**:

```sh
# Namespace variable notation only works with if you
# double(!)-backtick-escape the wildcard metacharacters:

# Assign to / implicitly create env. var '[foo]'
${env:``[foo``]} = 'bar'

# Get its value.
${env:``[foo``]}
```

Note:

- **Escaping shouldn't be required at all**, because there is no good reason to treat paths that conceptually identify a given, known item as wildcard expressions - see [GitHub issue #9225](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/9225).
- That *double* `` ` ``-escaping is needed is an added quirk - see [GitHub issue #7999](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/7999).
- **Another workaround** - one that doesn't involve escaping - is to use 
  `Set-Content -LiteralPath env:[foo] bar` and `Get-Content -LiteralPath env:[foo]`, but that is both verbose and slow.

---

As for **the other syntax variations you tried**:

> `$env:${[foo]}="bar"`

Since your variable reference isn't `{...}`-enclosed *as a whole* (except for the initial `$`), the token that follows the `:` is only allowed to contain characters that *do not require escaping* - and `$`, `{` and `}` all violate that rule.

- `{...}`-enclosing the entire path - `${env:[foo]}` - solves the *syntax* problem, but runs into the problem detailed above.

> `Set-Item -LiteralPath env:${[foo]} -Value "bar"`

This does *not* work in general, because *string expansion* is applied beforehand here - it is as if you had passed `"env:${[foo]}"`: the reference to a (regular) variable named `${[foo]}` is *expanded* (replaced with its value) and in effect appended to literal `env:`, *before* handing the result to `Set-Item`.

If such a regular variable doesn't exist, what `Set-Item` sees is just `env:` (because non-existent variables default to `$null`, which becomes the empty string in a string context), which causes an error due to the lack of variable name.

By contrast, the following would set an environment variable named `unrelated` instead:

```sh
# Create a regular variable literally named '[foo]'.
${[foo]} = 'unrelated'

# !! The following sets env:unrelated, i.e., env. var 'unrelated',
# !! due to the string expansion that is performed on the -LiteralPath
# !! argument up front.
Set-Item -LiteralPath env:${[foo]} bar

$env:unrelated # -> 'bar'
```

The same applies to `Get-Item -LiteralPath env:${[foo]}` and 
`Set-Item -LiteralPath env:${[foo]2} -Value "bar"`.