# Adding all module functions into foreach-Object -Parallel block

Tags: powershell, powershell-7.0

I have a list of API requests I need to make, and I'm trying to speed it up using Foreach-Object -Parallel:

```
$funcDef = ${function:Request-Something}.ToString()
$results = [System.Collection.ArrayList]@()

$requests | ForEach-Object -parallel {
    ${function:Request-Something} = $using:funcDef
    $null = ($using:results).add((Request-Something -request $_))
}
```

However, `Request-Something` calls a number of other custom functions from the same module, `APIHelpers.psm1`

I need a way to add all the necessary functions into that script block

I was considering building a hashtable that maps function names to function text, but I can't figure out the syntax for passing a variable to `$function`:

```
$funcDefs = @{}
(Get-Command -Module APIHelpers).Name | ForEach-Object {
    $name = $_
    $funcDefs[$name] = ${function:$`{name`}} #This does NOT work, I can't figure out the syntax
}
```

Once I have this hashtable built, I imagine I could modify the original code:

```
$requests | ForEach-Object -parallel {
    foreach ($funcName in $using:funcDefs.keys) {
        ${function:$funcName} = $using:funcDefs[$funcName]
    }
    $null = ($using:results).add((Request-Something -request $_))
}
```

Comment: Check out this answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67393819/recursively-call-a-function-from-itself-inside-a-foreach-object-parallel-block/67394964#67394964 might help you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> `` ${function:$`{name`}} `` #This does NOT work, I can't figure out the syntax

You're using [namespace variable notation](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55036515/45375), which only supports *literal* item names.<sup>[1]</sup>

Use the equivalent `Get-Content` call targeting the `function:` drive, which allows you to use variables:

```
$funcDefs[$name] = (Get-Content function:$name).ToString()
```

<sup>Alternatively, you could take a shortcut via `Invoke-Expression` (`iex`), which [should generally be avoided, however](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51252636/45375): `` (Invoke-Expression "`${function:$name}").ToString() ``</sup>

---

Taking a step back: Can't you just call `Import-Module` inside the `-Parallel` script block?

---

Note that, as a **future enhancement**, copying the caller's state to the parallel threads is being considered, which would mean that all functions the caller sees are implicitly available to the threads too; see [GitHub issue #12240](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/12240).

---

<sup>[1] In the sense that you cannot use variable names or expressions. The literally specified name is actually - and unexpectedly - interpreted as a *wildcard pattern*, as discussed in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55344037/45375).</sup>