# PowerShell - How to get Environment Variable value using wildcards

Tags: powershell, azure-devops, azure-pipelines, wildcard

I have some variables that i need to get the value from, the thing is that in the middle of the name i can have any possible value because it's the artifacts name.

Example:
I have these environment variables:
`RELEASE_ARTIFACTS__TESTECOMPLETEPR__PROJECTNAME`
`RELEASE_ARTIFACTS__TESTECOMPLETEPR_REPOSITORY_NAME`

And i need something like:
`$repoId = (Get-Item -Path Env:RELEASE_ARTIFACTS_*_REPOSITORY_ID).Value`
or
`$repoId = $Env:RELEASE_ARTIFACTS_*_REPOSITORY_ID`

But the `*` doesn't seem to work.
How can i do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Wildcard expressions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Wildcards) *are* supported, with *all* providers, in the `-Path` parameter of the [`Get-Item`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/get-item) cmdlet, and also with [`Get-Content`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/get-content), which is preferable here because it returns the environment-variable value *directly* (no need for `(...).Value`); to demonstrate:

```sh
$env:RELEASE_ARTIFACTS_FOO_REPOSITORY_ID = 1

Get-Content env:RELEASE_ARTIFACTS_*_REPOSITORY_ID # -> 1
```

---

Perhaps surprisingly, they are also supported when you use [namespace variable notation](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55036515/45375), though you must then enclose the reference in `{...}` (because a `*` would otherwise not be recognized as part of a variable name):

```sh
${env:RELEASE_ARTIFACTS_*_REPOSITORY_ID} # -> 1
```

**Caveats**:<sup>Tip of the hat to [Daniel](https://stackoverflow.com/users/11954025/daniel).</sup>

- **If the wildcard pattern matches *multiple* items** (environment variables in this case), **a statement-terminating *error* occurs**. Use the `Get-Content` (or `Get-Item`) approach to retrieve multiple values (items).

  - Given this awkwardness, along with the escaping pitfalls discussed below, **it would make sense *not* to support wildcard matching in namespace variable notation**, as suggested in [GitHub issue #9225](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/9225); while technically a breaking change, my sense is that not much real-world code would be impacted.
- Strangely, namespace variable notation *with wildcard patterns* does *not* work with *variables* (where the notation is rarely used to begin with, however, given that `$variable:foo` offers no advantage over `$foo`): <del>`${variable:HOM*}`</del> performs *no* wildcard matching and behaves like an undefined variable (it quietly evaluates to `$null` by default).

  - While the `Get-Content` / `Get-Item` approach does work, note that there's also a dedicated [`Get-Variable`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/get-variable) cmdlet (use `-ValueOnly` to get just the value) - e.g. `Get-Variable HOM* -ValueOnly` - which additionally supports accessing variables in *different scopes*, via the `-Scope` parameter.

---

**Namespace variable notation vs. `Get-Content`:**

- Namespace variable notation is both more concise and performs better (because a cmdlet call isn't involved).
- However, the `Get-Content` approach is sometimes required, namely when you use a *variable* to specify the environment-variable name or name pattern; that is, assuming variable definition `$envVarName = 'RELEASE_ARTIFACTS_*_REPOSITORY_ID'`:

  - <del>`${env:$envVarName}`</del> does *not* work,
  - but `Get-Content env:$envVarName` does.
- Escaping pitfalls:

  - Escaping wildcard metacharacters such as `[` that you want to be interpreted *verbatim* is currently challenging, due to the bugs discussed in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55344037/45375).
  - If the *whole* name should be used verbatim, you can avoid the need for escaping by using `Get-Content`'s `-LiteralPath` parameter instead; however, this isn't an option with namespace variable notation, where names are *invariably* treated as wildcard patterns.

Comment: Thank you, @Daniel - excellent points. I've added the info to the answer, with some extra commentary. `${variable:PSVer*Table}` not working is at the very least a strange inconsistency, though in the grand scheme of things I think it would have been wiser never to support wildcard matching in namespace variable to begin with; that is, `${env:someName}` should always have been the equivalent of `Get-Content -LiteralPath env:someName`, not `Get-Content `-Path env:someName` - that also solves the awkwardness of the error occurring with _multiple_ matches - see the linked GitHub issue.