# Powershell Variable replacement not working from command line

Tags: powershell

I have the following command I want to run from PowerShell:

```
docker run -v C:\src\docker_certs:/root/.dotnet/https -it MyContainer:MyTag /bin/bash
```

When I run that it works perfectly.  (It mounts a volume using the source folder at the destination folder.)

But when I run this:

```
docker run -v $env:DOCKER_CERTS_PATH:/root/.dotnet/https -it MyContainer:MyTag /bin/bash
```

The volume does not get mounted.

I run this to check the value:

```
echo $env:DOCKER_CERTS_PATH
```

And it returns:

> C:\src\docker_certs

As I understood things, it should have replaced the value of `$env:DOCKER_CERTS_PATH` with *C:\src\docker_certs* in the second command.

**How can I get the PowerShell reference to an environment variable to replace when I run a command?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Enclose the environment-variable reference in `{...}`:

```
docker run -v ${env:DOCKER_CERTS_PATH}:/root/.dotnet/https ...
```

Alternatively, `` ` ``-escape the `:` char. following the env.-var. reference:

```
docker run -v $env:DOCKER_CERTS_PATH`:/root/.dotnet/https ...
```

---

As for **what you tried**:

> `docker run -v $env:DOCKER_CERTS_PATH:/root/.dotnet/https ...`

**If you don't use `{...}` to explicitly delineate a variable name, PowerShell may have a different idea of where the variable name ends than you do**.

**As an alternative to using `{...}`, you can `` ` ``-escape the first character you don't want to be considered part of the variable name.**

Note that your command argument is in this case implicitly treated as if it were enclosed in `"..."`, so the above **applies to [expandable strings](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40445998/45375) (`"..."`)** too.

<sup>For an comprehensive discussion of how unquoted tokens are parsed as command arguments, see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41254359/45375).</sup>

In the case at hand, the `:` that follows `$env:DOCKER_CERTS_PATH` is *not* considered the end of the variable reference; instead, it is considered *part of the variable name*, so that PowerShell looks for an environment variable (`env:`) literally named `DOCKER_CERTS_PATH:` (sic).

Since no such environment variable (presumably) exists, `$env:DOCKER_CERTS_PATH:` expands to the *empty string* and all that is passed to docker is `/root/.dotnet/https`.

You can verify that `DOCKER_CERTS_PATH:` is a valid *environment* variable name as follows:

```
PS> $env:DOCKER_CERTS_PATH: = 'hi'; $env:DOCKER_CERTS_PATH:
hi
```

By contrast, a *regular* (shell) variable is *not* permitted to contain `:`, because that `:` - in the absence of a namespace prefix such as `env:` - is itself considered a namespace prefix, which fails, because then the variable-name part is missing:

```
PS> $DOCKER_CERTS_PATH: = 'hi' # BREAKS, even with {...}
Variable reference is not valid. ':' was not followed by a valid variable name character. Consider using ${} to delimit the name.
```

The *first* `:` in a variable identifier is *invariably* considered the end of the *namespace* identifier, which must refer to an *existing PowerShell* drive name, as reported by `Get-PSDrive`.
This notation is called *namespace variable notation*, as explained in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55036515/45375).

Comment: Glad to hear it was helpful, @Vaccano.