# PowerShell: Get-Item vs Get-ChildItem output types

Tags: powershell, sorting, get-childitem, sort-object

I was trying to print out environment variables in alphabetical order (by name), and the first thing I could come up with was:

```
Get-Item env: | Sort-Object -Property Name
```

But the output was always unsorted. Then I tried the following

```
Get-ChildItem env: | Sort-Object -Property Name
```

And got the expected, correctly sorted, output. This suggests that the output of `Get-Item` and `Get-ChildItem` is not of same type, even though the (formatted) output from `Get-Item env:` and `Get-ChildItem env:` looks precisely the same (i.e. dictionary)

Piping the output from the commands to `| Get-TypeData` revealed that `Get-Item env:` seems to actually return just single `System.Collections.DictionaryEntry`, whereas `Get-ChildItem env:` returns multiple `System.Collections.DictionaryEntry` objects.

Can someone explain what is precisely happening here? Why two seemingly different input data types produce identical looking output/string representation? Is PowerShell doing some implicit "unboxing" of the single-entry dictionary object from `Get-Item` output?

Using PowerShell 5.1 on Windows 10.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**tl;dr:**

- `Get-Item` isn't worth using with the `env:` drive's *root*; to enumerate the current process' environment variables, use `Get-ChildItem env:` instead.
- Generally, use `Get-Item` to get information about the targeted item *itself*, and `Get-ChildItem` to get information about its *children*.

---

`Get-Item` is designed to return a given item *itself*, whereas `Get-ChildItem` returns its *children*.

<sup>Note: `Get-ChildItem` *falls back* to the item itself for items that by definition cannot have children, such as individual environment variables or files - see bottom section.</sup>

`Get-Item env:` is akin to `Get-Item C:\` in that you're asking for the *root* of a PowerShell drive *itself*, not its children.

`env:` is the PowerShell drive that contains all environment variables defined in the current process, and *as itself* it currently has a representation of limited utility, only accessing its *children* works as expected.
(Contrast this with a root *directory* such as `C:\`, which has meaningful properties itself, such as timestamps, permissions, ...)

What PowerShell returns for the `env:` drive is the *collection of entries* from the dictionary it uses to store information about the individual environment variables *as a single object*<sup>[1]</sup>, which is usual behavior, in that commands are normally expected to send a collection's *elements* to the pipeline, *one by one*. That information about the item itself effectively includes the children too is unusual as well.

It is a moot point, because `Get-ChildItem env:` will give you the same functionality in a conceptually clearer manner, but you could use `(...)`, the [grouping operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Operators#grouping-operator--) to *force enumeration* of the items in the collection that `Get-Item env:` outputs:

```sh
# Currently the same as: Get-ChildItem env: | Sort-Object Name
(Get-Item env:) | Sort-Object Name
```

What would arguably more sense if PowerShell returned the *whole dictionary* rather than its *collection of entries*, so that you could access `.Keys` to get all environment-variable *names* and `.Values` to get all values. (Dictionaries / hashtables are *not* expected to be enumerated in PowerShell pipelines).

In fact, due to [*member-access enumeration*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44620191/45375), you could achieve the same effect by accessing properties `.Key` and `.Value` on the entry collection currently returned by `Get-Item env:`

```sh
(Get-Item env:).Name  # returns array of all env.-var. *names*; same as .Key 

(Get-Item env:).Value  # returns array of all *values*
```

---

**"Sloppy" use of `Get-ChildItem`**

As stated, for item types that by definition cannot have child items, `Get-ChildItem` falls back to `Get-Item` behavior, so that the following two commands are effectively equivalent:

```sh
Get-Item env:Path

# Same, because an environment variable can never have children,
# but it's better to use Get-Item.
Get-ChildItem env:Path
```

However, it is conceptually preferable to use `Get-Item` in such situations, given that it expresses the intent *unambiguously*.

As an aside: the commonly used `$env:PATH` syntax for directly retrieving a given environment variable's *value* is an instance of [namespace variable notation](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55036515/45375) and is the equivalent of
`Get-Content env:PATH` (not `Get-Item`).

---

<sup>[1] `Get-Item env:` returns the `.Values` property value of the [`` System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2 ``](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary-2) instance that PowerShell uses to store information about environment variables. That value is output as a single object, and its type is a collection type nested inside the dictionary type, [`` System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2.ValueCollection ``](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary-2.ValueCollection); you can inspect the type with `Get-Item env: | Get-Member`</sup>