# PowerShell string interpolation syntax

Tags: powershell, syntax, string-interpolation

I always used the following syntax to be sure that variable were expanded in a string:

`"my string with a $($variable)"`

I recently ran into the following syntax:

`"my string with a ${variable}"`

Are they equivalent? Any difference?

Comment: `$()` is the sub-expression operator. It can enclose complex expressions or simple things like accessing member properties. `${}` syntax is for when variable names have special symbols that otherwise standard `$variable` won't evaluate properly.

Comment: $() can also be used outside of strings to bring together multiple pipelines separated by a ";".

Comment: If anyone else here runs across issues with string interpolation, especially with nested hash table keys and values, I recommend setting the element you want to access as a temp variable with something like `.ToString()` or whatever data type would be appropriate. I wasted a lot of time trying to figure out why `Write-Output` was getting very different strings than the actual strings I was attempting to access, which showed up just fine when output to console directly.

Answer (score 151, accepted):

**tl;dr**

Inside `"..."`:

- **`$(...)`** is only needed to embed entire *expressions* or *commands* (e.g. `"$($PSVersionTable.PSVersion)"`)
- **`${...}`** is only needed if a stand-alone reference to a variable that has a regular name needs *delimiting* (disambiguation), so that *subsequent characters* in the string aren't interpreted as part of the variable name (e.g, `"${foo}_bar"` correctly embeds variable `$foo`; without `{...}`, PowerShell would look for variable `$foo_bar`; notably, a subequent `:` requires this technique too: `"${foo}:bar"`)

Independently of use in `"..."`, `${...}` is also needed for variable names containing *special characters* (e.g. `${a-b} = 42`)

For a comprehensive overview of PowerShell's *expandable strings* (string interpolation), see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40445998/45375).

---

###### Background information:

To complement [marsze's helpful answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60323244/45375):

**`${...}`** (enclosing the variable name in `{` and `}`) is indeed ***always* necessary if a variable name contains *special characters***, such as **spaces, `.` or `-`**.

- *Not* special are `_` and - [surprisingly and problematically](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/11379) - `?`.

  - For the exact rules, see the relevant section of the conceptual "about_Variables" help topic, [Variable Names that Include Special Characters](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Variables#variable-names-that-include-special-characters).
- (The first occurrence of) **`:`** in a name is *invariably* interpreted as terminating either a PowerShell *drive reference* - in the context of [*namespace variable notation*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55036515/45375) - or a [*scope specifier*](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Variables#variables-and-scope), irrespective of whether `{...}` enclosure is used or required (e.g., in `$env:USERNAME` or `${env:USERNAME}`, `env` refers to the [`Env:` PowerShell drive](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Environment_Provider) representing all environment variables; in `$script:foo` or `${script:foo}`, `script` refers to the script's scope and its variables).

Note:

- `${...}` - the syntax for disambiguating a variable *name* - is **not to be confused with `$(...)`**, the **[subexpression *operator*](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Operators#subexpression-operator--), which is needed to embed any expression or command that goes *beyond* a stand-alone variable reference inside `"..."`**, an [expandable (interpolating) string](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Quoting_Rules#double-quoted-strings).
- As such, **these two syntax forms are independent of one another and may need to be *combined*** in a given situation; e.g. `"$var"` / `"${var}"` work fine, but `"$var.someProperty"` / `"${var}.someProperty"` do *not*: you need `"$($var.someProperty)"` / `"$(${var}.someProperty)"`

**In the context of `"..."`**, there is *another* reason to **use `${...}`**, even if the variable name itself doesn't need it:

If you need **to delineate the variable name from directly following non-whitespace characters**, notably including `:`:

```bash
$foo = 'bar'  # example variable

# INCORRECT: PowerShell assumes that the variable name is 'foobarian', not 'foo'
PS> "A $foobarian."
A .  # Variable $foobarian doesn't exist -> reference expanded to empty string.

# CORRECT: Use {...} to delineate the variable name:
PS> "A ${foo}barian."
A barbarian.

# INCORRECT: PowerShell assumes that 'foo:' is a *namespace* (drive) reference
#            (such as 'env:' in $env:PATH) and FAILS:
PS> "$foo: bar"
Variable reference is not valid. ':' was not followed by a valid variable name character. 
Consider using ${} to delimit the name.

# CORRECT: Use {...} to delineate the variable name:
PS> "${foo}: bar"
bar: bar
```

See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40445998/45375) for a comprehensive overview of PowerShell string-expansion rules.

Note that **you need the same technique when string expansion is *implicitly* applied, in the context of passing an *unquoted argument* to a command**; e.g.:

```bash
# INCORRECT: The argument is treated as if it were enclosed in "...",
#            so the same rules apply.
Write-Output $foo:/bar

# CORRECT
Write-Output ${foo}:/bar
```

---

Finally, a somewhat obscure alternative is to `` ` ``-escape the first character after the variable name, but the problem is that this only works as expected with characters that aren't part of *escape sequences* (see [`about_Special_Characters`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Special_Characters)):

```bash
# OK: because `: is not an escape sequence.
PS> "$foo`: bar"
bar: bar

# NOT OK, because `b is the escape sequence for a backspace character.
PS> "$foo`bar"
baar # The `b "ate" the trailing 'r' of the variable value
     # and only "ar" was the literal part.
```

Answer (score 29):

Note that `$()` is helpful for json objects:

```
"My json property is $($jsonObj.property)"
```

Comment: This is what I needed for ordinary PowerShell expressions, too.

Comment: To elaborate on @Grault's comment: `{` and `}` in `${var}` are syntax elements in the context of referencing a _variable_ alone, to disambiguate its _name_. By contrast, `$(...)` is the subexpression _operator_. As such, the two syntax forms are independent of one another and may need to be _combined_ in a given situation.
You need `$(...)` inside `"..."` for any expression that goes _beyond_ a _stand-alone_ variable reference; e.g. `"$var"` / `"${var}"` work fine, but `"$var.someProperty"` / `"${var}.someProperty"` do _not_: you need `"$($var.someProperty)"` / `"$(${var}.someProperty)"`

Answer (score 24):

`${variable}` is the syntax for variable names that include **special characters**.

(See [about_Variables -> Variable names that include special characters](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_variables?view=powershell-7#variable-names-that-include-special-characters)
)

Example:

```
${var with spaces} = "value"
"var with spaces: ${var with spaces}"
```

So in your case it's basically the same as simply writing `$variable`