# Why does Powershell not process a string correctly which has a dollar sign and a question mark?

Tags: powershell, special-characters, dollar-sign

In PowerShell, why does this return nothing:

```
PS > $y = "$prid?api"
PS > echo $y
```

But these work better:

```
PS > $y = "$prid\?api"
PS > echo $y
18\?api
PS > $y = "${prid}?api"
PS > echo $y
18?api
```

Comment: Check out this post [PowerShell string interpolation syntax](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60323111/powershell-string-interpolation-syntax)

Comment: In case you're interested: I've added info regarding the v7.1+ _null-conditional_ operator, (`?.` and `?[...]`), which clashes with the permissiveness of allowing use of `?` as part of a variable name without `{...}`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Surprisingly, `?` can be used in a PowerShell variable name *without requiring that the name be enclosed in `{...}`*.

Therefore, based on the rules of PowerShell's [expandable strings](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40445998/45375) (string interpolation inside `"..."` strings), `"$prid?api"` looks for a variable with verbatim name `prid?api` rather than considering the `?` to implicitly terminate the preceding identifier.

That is, you can actually define and reference a variable named `prid?api` as follows:

```
PS> $prid?api = 'hi'; $prid?api
hi
```

This surprising permissiveness actually gets in the way of a recently introduced language feature, *null-conditional access*, introduced in PowerShell (Core) 7.1:

```
# v7.1+; note that the {...} around the name is - unexpectedly - *required*.
${variableThatMayBeNull}?.Foo()
```

[GitHub issue #14025](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/14025) advocates for obviating the need to use `{...}` in this case.