# How to activate a file using powershell functions (related to python)?

Tags: python-3.x, powershell, python-venv

I want to create a venv (virtual environment) using this python command in windows 10

```
python -m venv "environment name"
```

and to activate it I have to enter this line in powershell

`"environment name"\scripts\activate` or `"environment name"\scripts\activate.bat`

so I created a this function in $profile

```
function active {
    param (
        $venv_name = "venv"
    )
    
    "$($venv_name)\scripts\activate.bat"
}
```

but the problem is this function only shows the path and nothing more but I want it to activate

`"environment name"\scripts\activate.bat`

How can I fix this ?

and it doesn't have to be function

Comment: Recent Python version have the file `.\Scripts\activate.ps1`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the invocation operator `&`:

```
function active {
    param (
        $venv_name = "venv"
    )
    
    & "$($venv_name)\scripts\activate.bat"
}
```

You can also simplify the string slightly, `$()` is not required for simple variable expansion:

```
& "${venv_name}\scripts\activate.bat"
```

Comment: What's the reason for `${..}`?

Comment: @AbrahamZinala, have a look here https://stackoverflow.com/a/60329476/11954025

Comment: @AbrahamZinala At some point you're going to run into a situation where you'll want to use a variable to store a drive letter or similar, best be in the habit of qualifying them with `${...}`, otherwise you'll get nasty surprises :) `$DriveLetter = 'C'; "$DriveLetter:\Windows"` vs `"${DriveLetter}:\Windows"`

Comment: Oh man, that's cool. Wasn't aware of that. Thanks to both of you, for the explanation and link. Don't mind me and my comments; just a curious mind at work(: