# PowerShell wget call from a function with hostname as parameter

Tags: powershell

I'm trying to do a function to get a server version from `wget` in PowerShell (in my PowerShell profile), I first tried this:

```
function GetTotoVersion($hostname)
{
    wget "http://$hostname:8080/toto/version" | Select-Object -ExpandProperty Content
}
```

After some search and according to other answers I tried (not sure it makes sense in my case but tried anyway):

```
function GetTotoVersion($hostname)
{
    $hostname = ($hostname -replace '"', "")
    wget "http://$hostname:8080/toto/version" | Select-Object -ExpandProperty Content
}
```

I tried also setting URI in a variable:

```
function GetTotoVersion($hostname)
{
    $uri = "http://$hostname:8080/toto/version"
    wget "$uri" | Select-Object -ExpandProperty Content
}
```

Tried also using variables inside `{}` (`${hostname}` and `${uri}`) without success too.

But I always got following error (hostname is blank):

```
Invoke-WebRequest : Cannot bind parameter 'Uri'. Cannot convert value "http:///toto/version" to type "System.Uri". Error: "Invalid URI: The hostname could not be parsed."
C:\Users\me\Documents\WindowsPowerShell\Microsoft.PowerShell_profile.ps1:20 char:10
+     wget "http://$hostname:8080/toto/version" | Select-Object -Expand ...
+          ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (:) [Invoke-WebRequest], ParameterBindingException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CannotConvertArgumentNoMessage,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.InvokeWebRequestCommand
```

Any idea ?

Comment: Why do you have three forward slashes in a row? "http:///toto/version"

Comment: This question is tagged [tag:wget] - are you aware that `wget` (in PowerShell) is not actually `wget`, but an alias for the `Invoke-WebRequest` cmdlet?

Comment: Where are you calling your function `GetTotoVersion`?

Comment: How do you call the `GetTotoVersion`?

Comment: Yes I know `wget` is an alias for `Invoke-WebRequest`, in any case I don't even know why I tagged `wget` (that I'll remove) since this is a pure PowerShell issue. 

And I call `GetTotoVersion HostnameWhereTotoServerRuns`, from anywhere since I put it in my PowerShell profile as I said. 

In any case, now I got a fix, in this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/77692427/11159476

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @jdweng pointed out, the function is actually passing *"http:///toto/version"* to `wget` because of an issue with string interpolation. When you replace wget code line invocation for:

```
write "http://$hostname:8080/toto/version"
```

and pass "myhost" it prints

> http:///toto/version

In order to prevent that issue, try this: `"http://${hostname}:8080/toto/version"`

```ps
function GetTotoVersion($hostname)
{
    wget "http://${hostname}:8080/toto/version" | Select-Object -ExpandProperty Content
}
```

You may get an error if, for instance, domain doesn't exist. But not the one you have reported in your question.

Comment: Indeed it works, I though I tried this but as you said maybe I misread the error... In any case, thanks !

Answer (score 2):

To complement [derloopkat's helpful answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77692427/45375) with some **background information**:

**PowerShell variables can have a `:`-separated *prefix***, with the prefix either specifying a [*scope*](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Scopes) (e.g, `$script:foo`) or a [*namespace*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55036515/45375) (e.g, `$env:USERNAME`).

Therefore, **`$hostname:8080` *as a whole* is interpreted to be a variable reference** in [expandable (interpolating), double-quoted strings (`"..."`)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Quoting_Rules#double-quoted-strings), as well as in *unquoted command arguments*, which are *implicitly* parsed as if they were expandable strings (e.g., `Write-Output $hostname:8080` is equally broken).

Since `$hostname:` isn't a valid scope or namespace specifier, the whole reference expands to `$null`, which in the context of string interpolation becomes the *empty string*. In effect, the reference is simply *removed* from the resulting string.

**Enclose the variable name in `{...}` to delimit it**, possibly including an intentional prefix;
e.g., `${foo}` or `${script:foo}`

Therefore, `.../${hostname}:8080/...` is an effective solution.

Note:

- **`{...}` enclosure is also *generally* needed if a variable name contains *nonstandard characters***, such as `.` or `-`.
- Curiously, **`?` is *not* a nonstandard character**, so that a `?` following a variable reference too requires `{...}` enclosure; e.g., `"Is this $HOME?"` yields verbtaim `Is this` , because `$HOME?` is seen as the variable reference; `"Is this ${HOME}?"` fixes this problem.

See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60329476/45375) for more information.

Comment: Thanks for the complement of information, very helpful ! And I don't know why I don't use this in PowerShell because on Linux bash I always use ${var}...

Comment: Glad to hear it helped, @gluttony. `${var}` is not just technically unambiguous, but also visually distinctive - but it's cumbersome to type; and it takes some getting used to that a `:` or `?` following a variable reference _requires_ `${var}`