# docker build command with variable in gitlab CI

Tags: docker, gitlab-ci

I have following docker command in gitlab CI file `.gitlab-ci.yml`

```
docker build --pull -t "${CI_REGISTRY_IMAGE:$CI_COMMIT_REF_SLUG}" .
```

getting following error after build stage:

> invalid argument "." for "-t, --tag" flag: invalid reference format
> See 'docker build --help'.

any help , how to pass the variables ? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way you've defined the tag is incorrect, and the result will be an empty string. That's why you get an error regarding the tag.

There is no need to add brackets, and you can use `$ENV_VARIABLE`. In this case, you can use the following command:

```
docker build --pull -t "$CI_REGISTRY_IMAGE:$CI_COMMIT_REF_SLUG" .
```

If you want to use `brackets`:

```
docker build --pull -t "${CI_REGISTRY_IMAGE}:${CI_COMMIT_REF_SLUG}" .
```

Comment: I used the first option without brackets : getting below error

Comment: At C:\Windows\TEMP\build_script133493204\script.ps1:249 char:25
+ docker build --pull -t "$CI_REGISTRY_IMAGE:$CI_COMMIT_REF_SLUG" .
+                         ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
Variable reference is not valid. ':' was not followed by a valid variable name character. Consider using ${} to 
delimit the name.
    + CategoryInfo          : ParserError: (:) [], ParseException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : InvalidVariableReferenceWithDrive

Comment: Did the second option (using brackets) work for you? And are you using Windows as the host OS for your Gitlab? If yes, maybe you should take a look at the documentation:

https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/variables/#use-cicd-variables-in-job-scripts

Comment: This link may also help you: 

Powershell - Variable reference is not valid. ':' was not followed by a valid variable name character
https://stackoverflow.com/a/61582833/3907548