# Can Ansible's win_powershell thoroughly process a boolean

Tags: powershell, ansible, boolean-expression

`win_powershell` seems to choke when I attempt to pass a Boolean variable through it to register a tested discrete state on a remote guest/target (for later consumption).  For numerous attempts to provide compliant statements, I get errors such as ...

- `was not followed by a valid variable name character. Consider using ${} to delimit the name.`
- `Last close parenthesis is an invalid character`
- `Cannot convert string to bool`
- `Colon is unexpected token`
- `$True is unexpected token`
- `Unable to convert to dictionary`
- `Must either be a JSON string or in the key=value form`

My goal was to use the win_powershell module to execute a powershell script ...

```
  $IsInstalled = ((gp HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\*).DisplayName -Match "Microsoft SQL Server").Length -gt 0
```

... on a remote host and consume the `IsInstalled` variable later in the Playbook.  (the p/s statement executes flawlessy when invoked directly).

My task ended up looking like the below with all of the various/unsuccessful attempts commented out. Notice that I resorted to the simplest of tests in the end which infers that processing a boolean via win_powershell is not do-able. I'm hoping somebody can prove me wrong and/or confirm that I need to get such resolve by processing a string variable instead.

BTW (for the innocent by-stander) there are no hits for the word bool in the Ansible documentation for win_powershell.  However, the description for parameters includes the word dictionary and term key=value pairs. If these descriptions are restraints, it should be (I wish it were) stated as such (more emphatic).

Key points observed along the way, …

- An = operator always produces a string; use json syntax for other variable types; a : (colon) for other types such as boolean.
- Consider using ${} to delimit the variable name (but how?)
- Enclose any boolean equates with single ‘
- I found some other blogs/posts but nothing in layman (json newbie) terms (that I could understand).

Anybody have a solution to make a Boolean work as sought or should I (just) try to process the needed state as a string variable?  Check out these blogs …

[powershell - Variable reference is not valid. ':' was not followed by a valid variable name character](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61581718/powershell-variable-reference-is-not-valid-was-not-followed-by-a-valid-va)
[How can you use an object's property in a double-quoted string?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1145704/how-can-you-use-an-objects-property-in-a-double-quoted-string/40445998#40445998)

Here's my task efforts (with failed statements being commented) ...

```yaml
   - name: Test for installed SQL Server
      ansible.windows.win_powershell:
        script: |
          [CmdletBinding()]
          param (
            [bool]$IsInstalled
          )
          # $IsInstalled = ((gp HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\*).DisplayName -Match "Microsoft SQL Server").Length -gt 0
          # $IsInstalled: ((gp HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\*).DisplayName -Match "Microsoft SQL Server").Length -gt 0
          # $IsInstalled: ${ ((gp HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\*).DisplayName -Match "Microsoft SQL Server").Length -gt 0 }
          # ${IsInstalled}: ((gp HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\*).DisplayName -Match "Microsoft SQL Server").Length -gt 0
          # if ( ((gp HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\*).DisplayName -Match "Microsoft SQL Server").Length -gt 0 ) # last close paren is invalid character
          # if ( '((gp HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\*).DisplayName -Match "Microsoft SQL Server").Length -gt 0' ) # cannot convert string to bool
          if ( $False ) # a sanity check ...
             # { $IsInstalled: $True }
             # { ${ $IsInstalled}: $True }
             # { ${IsInstalled}: $True } # colon is unexpected token 
             # { ${IsInstalled} = $True } # equals outputs a string; cannot convert to boolean (i knew that but what the hey)
             # { ${ $IsInstalled: } $True } # unexpected token $True
             { '$IsInstalled: $True' }
          else
             # { $IsInstalled: $False }
             # { ${ $IsInstalled}: $False }
             # { ${IsInstalled}: $False }
             # { ${IsInstalled} = $False }
             # { ${ $IsInstalled: } $False }
             { '$IsInstalled: $False' }
        parameters:
          # IsInstalled: $True # cannot convert string to bool
          # 'IsInstalled: $True' # is of type System.String ... unable to convert to dict ... must either be a JSON string or in the key=value form"
}
      register: SQLtest
```

I was expecting the first (commented) statement to work; done. That is, to register SQLtest.IsInstalled as a boolean state for later consumption.

Comment: That's a lot of text for a very simple problem. To start with and avoid confusion. more or less everything that goes through jinja2 templating in ansible is a string. To fix your problem, don't register a variable in your poswershell. Have your snippet output either `True` or `False` as a textual content on the standard output, call the script trhough ansible, register the varialble... and your result is next in `{{ SQLtest.stdout | bool }}`

Comment: Moreover, you are doing all this to check if a software is installed when [there's already an existing module for that](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/windows/win_package_module.html)

Comment: For your next question, please avoid pasting special characters for bullet lists, use the standard markdown formatting (i.e. `* `) and make sure your code and text are formatted correctly. I edited your question to make it readable on screen. You can have a look at those changes for reference by clicking the `Edited xxxx ago` link above. Thanks

Comment: Sorry for the all the text; as an Ansible newbie, i just thought there must be a way to get a boolean thru this ...  As for the win_package module, that's actually my root problem; when i run that against an instance with the subject software already installed, it takes 10 minutes for it fail with unexpected RC.  My snippet executes instantly and i wanted to consume the boolean from that as a when-conditional for the win_package module.  Yea; i'll go for the string output

Answer (score 1):

Here's an exact solution that did work; i couldn't get the templating to work, ...

```
    - name: Test for installed SQL Server
        ansible.windows.win_powershell:
          script: |
            ((gp HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\*).DisplayName -Match "Microsoft SQL Server 2019 ").Length -gt 0
        register: SQLtest
```

... as consumed later in a when conditional ...

```
    when: not SQLtest.output
```

It's always simple (once you know how) ...