# Calling function as parameter in powershell cmdlet

Tags: powershell

```
function test([string]$word){
return $word
}

Get-ADUser -Identity Function:\test("bill")
```

From what I can tell the above should work.  MS has an example below where it looks like they call a function as a parameter.  But its not working for me.

MS example.

Get-ChildItem -Path Function:\Get-*Version | Remove-Item

Link - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/scripting/learn/ps101/09-functions?view=powershell-7.1

Comment: you will need to enclose the func AND its parameter[s] in parens to force the func to evaluate BEFORE the value is passed to the calling func/cmdlet.

Comment: As an aside: PowerShell functions, cmdlets, scripts, and external programs must be invoked _like shell commands_ - `foo arg1 arg2` - _not_ like C# methods - `foo('arg1', 'arg2')`.  
If you use `,` to separate arguments, you'll construct an _array_ that a command sees as a _single argument_.  
To prevent accidental use of method syntax, use [`Set-StrictMode -Version 2`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/set-strictmode) or higher, but note its other effects. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65208621/45375) for more information.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To pass a command's / expression's output as a command argument, use `(...)`, the [grouping operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Operators#grouping-operator--):

```
Get-ADUser -Identity (test "bill")
```

---

As for the `Function:\test` syntax: you can only use that for retrieving function *definitions*, not for direct *invocation*.

The syntax relies on the `Function:` PowerShell drive, which provides access to all function definitions - see the [about_Providers](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Providers) conceptual help topic.

For the sake of completeness (there's no good reason to take this approach here): Using [namespace variable notation](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55036515/45375) and `&`, the [call operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Operators#call-operator-), you *could* leverage the `Function:\test` path syntax - albeit without the `\` - as follows:

```
# Same as above.
Get-ADUser -Identity  (& $Function:test "bill")
```