# How to refer to a PowerShell function defined in a parent scope?

Tags: function, powershell, scope

I'm writing a PowerShell script that runs a couple of background jobs. Some of these background jobs will use the same set of constants or utility functions, like so:

```
$FirstConstant = "Not changing"
$SecondConstant = "Also not changing"
function Do-TheThing($thing)
{
    # Stuff
}

$FirstJob = Start-Job -ScriptBlock {
    Do-TheThing $using:FirstConstant
}

$SecondJob = Start-Job -ScriptBlock {
    Do-TheThing $using:FirstConstant
    Do-TheThing $using:SecondConstant
}
```

If I wanted to share variables (or, in this case, constants) in child scopes, I'd prefix the variable references with `$using:`. I can't do that with functions, though; running this code as-is returns an error:

```
The term 'Do-TheThing' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program.
```

My question is this: **How can my background jobs use a small utility function that I've defined in a higher scope?**

Comment: I'm unsure if I get your point. I cannot reproduce this error. As long as you define the function in the same PowerShell session you start the jobs in it should work actually.

Comment: @Olaf: Background jobs see neither variables nor functions from the caller's scope.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If the function in the higher scope is in the same (non-)module scope in the *same session*, your code *implicitly* sees it, due to PowerShell's dynamic scoping.

However, *background jobs* run in a *separate process* (child process), so anything from the caller's scope must be passed *explicitly* to this separate session.

This is trivial for *variable* values, with the [`$using:` scope](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_scopes#the-using-scope-modifier), but less obvious for *functions*, but it can be made to work with a bit of duplication, by passing a function's *body* via [*namespace variable notation*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55036515/45375):

```
# The function to call from the background job.
Function Do-TheThing { param($thing) "thing is: $thing" }

$firstConstant = 'Not changing'

Start-Job {

  # Define function Do-TheThing here in the background job, using
  # the caller's function *body*.
  ${function:Do-TheThing} = ${using:function:Do-TheThing}

  # Now call it, with a variable value from the caller's scope
  Do-TheThing $using:firstConstant

} | Receive-Job -Wait -AutoRemoveJob
```

The above outputs `'thing is: Not changing'`, as expected.