# Powershell startjob import-module call function with arguments

Tags: function, powershell, arguments, start-job, scriptblock

So I am trying to start-job from a module I wrote.

Copy-Modules.psm1

```
function startcopy([string] $ShowToCopy) {
  if (-not($ShowToCopy)) { return "No name provided. Doing nothing." }
  } else { return "Name Provided $ShowToCopy" }
}
```

in the main script I am calling it as follows:

```
$Copyname = "test"

Start-Job -Name "copy1" -InitializationScript { Import-Module -Name .\Copy-Modules.psm1 } -ScriptBlock {startcopy} -ArgumentList $Copyname
```

However the arguments never seems to go through. No matter how I format or pass the argument with switch or without I always get the result No name provided. Doing nothing.

Comment: Enclosed the path in quotes and/or use the full, not relative path.

Answer (score 1):

The **simplest solution** - assuming you need no other functions from your `Copy-Modules.psm1` module - is to pass your function's *body* as [`Start-Job`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/start-job)'s `-ScriptBlock` argument:

```sh
Start-Job -Name "copy1" -ScriptBlock $function:startcopy -ArgumentList $Copyname
```

`$function:startcopy` uses [namespace variable notation](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55036515/45375) to get the `startcopy`'s *body* as a [script block](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Script_Blocks).

Note:

- This obviates the need to define your `startcopy` function in the scope of the background job (which is an independent session in a child process that knows nothing about the caller's state), which is what your `-InitializationScript` script block does.
- The only limitation of this approach is that the script block won't be *named*, i.e. the original function name is lost, and `$MyInvocation.MyCommand.Name` inside the function returns the empty string.

---

As for **what you tried**:

- **It is the script block *as a whole* that receives the (invariably *positional* arguments** passed to `-ArgumentList`, **which you'll have to *pass on explicitly*** to any commands called inside the script block, using the [automatic **`$args`** variable](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Automatic_Variables#args):

```sh
$Copyname = "test"

# Note the use of $args[0]
Start-Job -Name "copy1" `
  -InitializationScript { Import-Module -Name .\Copy-Modules.psm1 } `
  -ScriptBlock { startcopy $args[0] } -ArgumentList $Copyname
```