# How to get powershell function source with full header

Tags: powershell

As seen here https://superuser.com/questions/414036/get-definition-of-function-and-echo-the-code this would get the body of test-function

```
${function:test-function}
```

but not the header of test-function with parameters

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**You'll have to add the missing parts yourself** (`function <name> { ... }`) in order to form a full function definition:

```bash
$funcDef = "function test-function { ${function:test-function} }"
```

If you're given the function name in a variable or you want to avoid repeating the function name:

```bash
$funcName = 'test-function'

$funcDef = "function $funcName { $(Get-Content function:$funcName) }"
```

Note that **the function body returned *does* include parameters**, in the form of a `param(...)` block - even if the original definition used the in-line parameter-declaration form. E.g., both `function test-function($foo) { 'foo' }` and `function test-function { param($foo) 'foo' }` result in body `param($foo) 'foo'` (with variations in whitespace).

---

**Background:**

`${function:test-function}` is an instance of [namespace variable notation](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55036515/45375), and therefore only works with *literal* names.

It returns the *body* of the specified function as a [script block](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Script_Blocks), which when stringified, results in the block's verbatim source code (without the `{` and `}` that you use to create a script-block *literal*.

`Get-Content function:test-function` is what the namespace variable notation translates into, except that the cmdlet-based enables use of variables in its arguments.