# How to determine if a given PSProvider uses variable syntax, e.g. $env:

Tags: powershell

In a nutshell, is there a way from the shell to determine if a [PSProvider's](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_providers?view=powershell-7.2) path has an accompanying variable and if so, what that variable is named?  The built-in PowerShell providers that support this notation are listed [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_variables?view=powershell-7.2#variable-syntax-with-provider-paths) but I'm referring to *any* provider in general - built-in/3rd party/custom etc.  Is it automatically the case that a provider's drive name (which can be exposed with `Get-PSProvider`) is always the same as its variable notation name?

For instance:

- The [Environment provider](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_environment_provider?view=powershell-7.2) uses the `Env:` drive which can also be accessed using its variable `$env:`
- The [Certificate provider](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.security/about/about_certificate_provider?view=powershell-7.2) uses the `Cert:` drive which can also be accessed using its variable `$cert:` but does *not* implement the IContentCmdletProvider interface -- as indicated by the following error message that's triggered in the shell when referencing a `$Cert:xyz` path (yet I can use <kbd>CTRL+Space</kbd> and <kbd>tab</kbd> to autocomplete `$cert:` paths)

  *The provider 'Certificate' cannot be used to get or set data using the variable syntax. Cannot use interface. The IContentCmdletProvider interface is not implemented by this provider.*

Does [this (quoted below)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_variables?view=powershell-7.2#variable-syntax-with-provider-paths) mean that every provider's drive(s) automatically use the variable notation (and will always have a corresponding variable), but not all provider drives are capable of exposing/manipulating their contents/items through the provider's variable syntax?

*"You can prefix a provider path with the dollar ($) sign, and access the content of any provider that implements the IContentCmdletProvider interface."*

Lastly, would the following be an accurate statement?
Asking "Is there a way from the shell to determine if a PSProvider implements the [IContentCmdletProvider](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.management.automation.provider.icontentcmdletprovider?view=powershellsdk-7.0.0#methods) interface?" probably isn't sufficient enough to determine if a provider's drive contents can be accessed/manipulated using its variable notation.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

PowerShell's [namespace variable notation](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55036515/45375) works meaningfully with:

- *drive names* ...
- ... of those PowerShell [providers](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Providers) that implement the [`[System.Management.Automation.Provider.IContentCmdletProvider]`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/System.Management.Automation.Provider.IContentCmdletProvider) interface ...
- with *literal* paths only (that is, basing paths on *variables* isn't support, although the literally specified paths are - surprisingly - interpreted as potential *wildcard* expression).

To list the *drives* in a given session that support this notation - based on the underlying provider's capabilities - use the following:

```bash
Get-PSDrive |
  Where-Object { 
    $_.Provider.Implementingtype.GetInterfaces() -contains [System.Management.Automation.Provider.IContentCmdletProvider] 
  }
```

To list the *providers* that support this notation, each of which may underly any number of drives - including none - in the current session (the `.Drives` property of each output object contains the list of current drives backed by that provider):

```bash
Get-PSProvider |
  Where-Object { 
    $_.Implementingtype.GetInterfaces() -contains [System.Management.Automation.Provider.IContentCmdletProvider] 
  }
```

---

As for **your questions**:

> Does this (quoted below) mean that every provider's drive(s) automatically use the variable notation (and will always have a corresponding variable), but not all provider drives are capable of exposing/manipulating their contents/items through the provider's variable syntax?

Indeed: While each drive's items can be *addressed* with namespace variable notation, it only *works* with those drives whose backing providers implements `IContentCmdletProvider`, because the notation's sole purpose is to access the *content* of provider items.

> Asking "Is there a way from the shell to determine if a PSProvider implements the IContentCmdletProvider interface?" probably isn't sufficient enough to determine if a provider's drive contents can be accessed/manipulated using its variable notation.

It *is* sufficient to test if a given provider implements `IContentCmdletProvider` (as shown above), assuming that said provider underlies one or more actual *drives* in the current session to access items by (as reflected in the output from [`Get-PSDrive`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/get-psdrive)).

PowerShell comes with *predefined* drives; you can define additional ones with [`New-PSDrive`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/new-psdrive)

Comment: Thank you for the insight and answers.  Super helpful!

Comment: I am glad to hear it, @Paulπ; my pleasure. Thanks for asking a good question.