# PowerShell, how to output contents of a function

Tags: powershell, function, parsing

I know that this works to view the contents of a function:

```
cat function:\mkdir
```

That's fine, so I thought I'd use the `bat` to syntax highlight that output

```
PS C:\> bat function:\mkdir
function:\mkdir: No such file or directory
```

I thought this might work:

```
PS C:\> bat $(function:\mkdir)
function:\mkdir : The term 'function:\mkdir' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try
again.
At line:1 char:7
+ bat $(function:\mkdir)
+        ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (function:\mkdir:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException
```

This also fails:

```
cat function:\mkdir | bat
```

What am I doing wrong; how can I output the function contents with a parser of my choice?

For some context, this is for my function that tells me as much information as possible about any cmdlet, function, alias, module, external script, application, or variable, just point `what` at any object and it will tell you about that object (e.g. `what mkdir` or `what what` etc). If `bat` is on the path, it will use that and colourise the output as PowerShell, and if not, it will use `Get-Content`. https://gist.github.com/roysubs/20c1bc888383d56df67008f4ba4179cb

Comment: Out of curiosity - what is `bat`?

Comment: you mean [this bat](https://github.com/sharkdp/bat)? It's a native application and not a powershell cmdlet so obviously it can't receive a powershell object

Comment: yes, that's the tool. It's a very useful (for me) `cat` replacement that syntax highlights all code files. I put it somewhere on my path and then do `function ca { bat $args -p }`  (the -p makes it act like a normal parser, like normal `cat` output, and I use `ca` instead of `cat` to not interfere with `cat` default), and then I can view files on the console in Technicolour ©™® instead of drab black and white.

Comment: Ok, it can't receive the object. How can I then turn that object into text? I tried using `out-string` also and that didn't help. i.e. how can I allow `bat` to manipulate the output of `function:\mkdir`

Comment: the function: provider outputs a scriptblock object. Maybe you can do something like `bat ((cat Function:\mkdir).toString())`, but you might have to trim line endings or something. Or you can copy the whole thing with `cat function:\mkdir | Set-Clipboard` and paste it into something with highlighting

Comment: It's not *irrelevant*, but maybe more of a superuser questions. Ok, I'll close it, just was confused by this. Thanks CptWhale, that's perfect, works great..

Comment: The main problem here is that you're trying to use a `cat`-replacement in place of something that _isn't_ cat - `cat` in PowerShell is an alias for `Get-Content`, and as @Cpt.Whale explains it works natively with _all_ of PowerShell's content providers, not just the file system.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use *namespace variable notation*:

```
# As argument.
bat $function:mkdir

# Via the pipeline
$function:mkdir | bat
```

Note:

- If the function name contains special characters, such as `-`, enclose the entire identifier in `{...}`, such as `${function:Get-Foo}`.
- As an aside:

  - As noted, in PowerShell *on Windows*, `cat` is a built-in alias for `Get-Content`. By contrast, in PowerShell on *Unix-like* platforms, `cat` refers to the standard Unix utility (`/bin/cat`).

In short:

- `$function:mkdir` is the equivalent of `Get-Content function:mkdir`

  - See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55036515/45375) for details.
- The result is a [`[scriptblock]`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Script_Blocks) instance, which is implicitly *stringified* when you pass it to an *external program*, such as `bat` in your case.

  - A script block conveniently stringifies to its *verbatim content*, i.e. to its *source code*. (In the case of a script-block *literal* - `{ ... }` - the `{` and `}` are *not* included).
- Namespace variable notation only works with *literal* function names; use the `Get-Content` equivalent if the function must be supplied via a *variable* or expression:

  ```
  $cmd = 'mkdir'

  # As argument.
  bat (Get-Content function:$cmd)

  # Via the pipeline
  (Get-Content function:$cmd) | bat
  ```