# Start-job invoke function from different powershell

Tags: powershell

In Powershell with the function Start-Job you can call functions if you initialize them beforehand.

```
$export_functions = 
{
    Function Log($message) {Write-Host $message}
    Function MyFunction($message) {Log($message)}
}

$param1="Hello stack overflow!"
Start-Job -ScriptBlock {MyFunction $using:param1} -InitializationScript $export_functions -ArgumentList @($param1) | Wait-Job | Receive-Job
```

Would it be possible to use a 'global' function inside the script block as well?
So something like:

```
Function Log($message) {Write-Host $message}

$export_functions = 
{
    Function Log($message) {$Function:Log($message)}
    Function MyFunction($message) {Log($message)}
}

$param1="Hello stack overflow!"
Start-Job -ScriptBlock {MyFunction $using:param1} -InitializationScript $export_functions -ArgumentList @($param1) | Wait-Job | Receive-Job
```

Or is that not intended after all?

Comment: So you want `Write-Host` to write to your calling session from the job?

Comment: That was just an example actually. I want to call a function from a different powershell file, which adds logging lines to a specified file. This function is included in multiple powershell scripts.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way to capture the function definition from the caller's scope (defined *outside* the initialization script block) is to use an [expandable (double-quoted) string (`"..."`)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Quoting_Rules#double-quoted-strings), i.e. *string interpolation*, and then use [`[scriptblock]::Create()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/System.Management.Automation.ScriptBlock.Create) to create a script block from the result.

You can *combine* this technique with defining the code you want to place directly inside the script block as usual:

```
Function Log($message) { Write-Host $message }

# Use string interpolation to capture the body of function Log ($function:Log)
$export_functions = [scriptblock]::Create(
  "Function Log { $function:Log }`n" +
  {
    Function MyFunction($message) { Log $message }
  }
)

Start-Job -InitializationScript $export_functions { Log 'hi1'; MyFunction 'hi2' } | 
  Receive-Job -Wait -AutoRemoveJob
```

Note the use of `$function:Log` to refer to the `Log` function's *body*, which is an example of [*namespace variable notation*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55036515/45375).

Comment: I have removed that question, this is the answer I was looking for, thanks!