# Add a new line before each Powershell prompt (including the conda environment name)

Tags: powershell, conda, newline, environment, prompt

I am trying to add a new line before each Powershell prompt to improve readability as shown below.

Instead of:

```
(base) PS C:\Users\myname --> "Hello"
Hello
(base) PS C:\Users\myname --> "Wow"
Wow
```

I would like an output like this:

```
(base) PS C:\Users\myname --> "Hello"
Hello

(base) PS C:\Users\myname --> "Wow"
Wow

(base) PS C:\Users\myname -->
```

My powershell profile, which I have modified for my prompt and to add the conda environment hook as per other SO posts is as follows:

```
function Prompt
{
    $promptString = "PS " + $(Get-Location) + " -->"
    Write-Host "$promptString" -NoNewline -ForegroundColor Yellow
    return " "
}

%{& "C:\Users\myname\Anaconda3\Scripts\conda.exe" "shell.powershell" "hook"} | Out-String | Invoke-Expression
```

I have tried adding the new line parameter ("`n") to the function prompt as follows:

```
$promptString = "`nPS " + $(Get-Location) + " -->"
```

This gives me the output as:

```
(base)
PS C:\Users\myname -->
```

which is not what I want.

I also tried adding a Write-Host before the conda hook but that doesn't work either:

```
Write-Host `n | %{& "C:\Users\myname\Anaconda3\Scripts\conda.exe" "shell.powershell" "hook"} | Out-String | Invoke-Expression
```

It gives me the error:
"Invoke-Expression : Cannot bind argument to parameter 'Command' because it is an empty string."
So this doesn't work either.

I assume this should be a simple fix but I'm unable to find the right commands/place to put the command that will allow me to add that new line to improve readability of the code. Been googling for a while and though I've learned quite a bit doing so, just haven't been able to find a fix for quite some time, so looking to the Stack Overflow community for some help. Thank you in advance!

Comment: See following : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_special_characters?view=powershell-7.3

Answer (score 1):

You need to modify the `prompt` function *after* it has been modified by `conda.exe`, which you can do by placing the following *after* your `& "C:\Users\myname\Anaconda3\Scripts\conda.exe" "shell.powershell" "hook" | Out-String | Invoke-Expression` call in your [`$PROFILE`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Profiles) file (note that there's no need for `% { ... }`):

```
$function:prompt = @"
  Write-Host "`n" 
  $function:prompt
"@
```

This redefines the `prompt` function by emitting a newline (`` "`n" ``) before calling the previous `prompt` function's body, using [namespace variable notation](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55036515/45375).

Comment: I really appreciate the tip, thank you. I added your $function:prompt code after the conda.exe call (also, thank you for the note on removing the `% {...}`. 

While I get line breaks and the conda environment now, it appears I have lost the custom PS decoration i.e., `(base) PS C:\Users\myname --->`. It has gone back to the vanilla `(base) PS>` style, which appears to be the default conda style.

I went through the link you provided but just couldn't get the custom PS command to work. Any ideas? Thank you again!

Comment: That is curious, @Ray. Did you retain your custom `prompt` function definition before calling the `conda` command?

Comment: I did! Code below:

`function Prompt {Prior formatted PS} THEN DID

& "C:\Users\myname\Anaconda3\Scripts\conda.exe" "shell.powershell" "hook" | Out-String | Invoke-Expression

THEN DID $function:prompt = @"{Your code}"@ `

and the output was `(base) PS>`

Comment: @Ray, honestly, I have no explanation.

Answer (score 0):

Not the most elegant answer, but I found a way to do this by adding a Write-Host "" command within the Conda.psm1 profile as follows. Marking the inserted text within ****. Thank you for all the help!

```
    function global:prompt() {
    if ($Env:CONDA_PROMPT_MODIFIER) {
        *****Write-Host ""****
        $Env:CONDA_PROMPT_MODIFIER | Write-Host -NoNewline
    }
    CondaPromptBackup;
}
```