# set Windows Enviromental variable with a local powershell variable

Tags: powershell, environment-variables, indirection

I am trying to set and view windows enviromental variables using locally defined variables.  Actual code I tried.

```
   $strAllowGPU_Group   = "TF_FORCE_GPU_ALLOW_GROWTH"
    $strAllowGPU_True   = "True"
    $strUserEnvs        = "User"
    $strCUDAPath =  "C:\Program Files\NVIDIA GPU Computing Toolkit\CUDA\v11.8\bin"
    $strCheckForCUDA = "C:\Program Files\NVIDIA GPU Computing Toolkit\CUDA"
    $strWhat = $env:${strAllowGPU_Group}
    [System.Environment]::SetEnvironmentVariable(${strAllowGPU_Group},${strAllowGPU_True}, ${strUserEnvs})
```

I recceive the following error message.

> At C:\Users\pgmrdlm\My Drive (pgmrdlm@gmail.com)\DSLR Notes and
> backup\Software\Scripts\CudaForPixinsight\CudaForPixinsight.ps1:50
> char:13
>
> - ```
>   $strWhat = $env:${strAllowGPU_Group}
>   ```
> - ```
>              ~~~~~ Variable reference is not valid. ':' was not followed by a valid variable name character. Consider using ${} to
>   ```
>
> delimit    the name. At C:\Users\pgmrdlm\My Drive
> (pgmrdlm@gmail.com)\DSLR Notes and
> backup\Software\Scripts\CudaForPixinsight\CudaForPixinsight.ps1:50
> char:18
>
> - ```
>   $strWhat = $env:${strAllowGPU_Group}
>   ```
> - ```
>                   ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~ Unexpected token '${strAllowGPU_Group}' in expression or statement.
>   ```
>
>   - CategoryInfo          : ParserError: (:) [], ParseException
>   - FullyQualifiedErrorId : InvalidVariableReferenceWithDrive

This works, and it does exactly what I want.  Create a persistant windows variable:

```
[System.Environment]::SetEnvironmentVariable('TF_FORCE_GPU_ALLOW_GROWTH','True', 'User')
```

I know this is nothing but me not coding the variable names correctly, but I appoligise.  I just don't have a clue.

Thank you in advance.

Dan

Comment: Why do you use curly braces for your variables? Have you tried the more common way? ... `$strAllowGPU_Group` instead of `${strAllowGPU_Group}`  `¯\_(ツ)_/¯` ... `$strWhat = $env:strAllowGPU_Group`

Comment: This is the actual statement I want to uses. `if ($null -eq $env:${strAllowGPU_Group}) {
  [System.Environment]::SetEnvironmentVariable(${strAllowGPU_Group},${strAllowGPU_True}, ${strUserEnvs})
 } else {
  write-host 
  write-host "An existing enviromental path for CUDA already exists.  Uninstall that version of CUDA and restart script"
  write-host $regexAddPath
  exit
 }`

Comment: I believe Olaf is wanting you to try this: `[System.Environment]::SetEnvironmentVariable($strAllowGPU_Group,$strAllowGPU_True, $strUserEnvs)`

Comment: @OldAndRetired Again ... try to remove the curly braces from your variables. Just like Darin shows. Thanks Darin 

Comment: Thanks everyone, the System.Enviroment without my curly brackes worked.  Again, thank you very much

Comment: There should not be a `$` before the variable name inside the `Env:` drive. Only use a `$` as the first character. `$Env:strUserEnvs` If LEFT CURLY BRACKET and RIGHT CURLY BRACKET characters make you happy; `${Env:strUserEnvs}`.

Comment: To summarize: The use of `{...}` around variable names is always an option, and isn't the problem here. The problem is the syntactically broken attempt to use _variable indirection_ via `$env:${strAllowGPU_Group}`, which isn't supported: what follows `$env:` must be a _verbatim_ environment-variable name and mustn't be a _reference to another variable_ that contains the name. To test if an environment variable whose name is stored in variable `${strAllowGPU_Group}` is defined, use `Test-Path Env:${strAllowGPU_Group}`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**tl;dr**

- `$env:${strAllowGPU_Group}` is *invalid syntax*: you cannot *indirectly* access an environment variable this way, via a name stored in *another variable* (`${strAllowGPU_Group}`)
  Use `Get-Content -ErrorAction Ignore Env:$strAllowGPU_Group`
  (if you know that the variable to exists, you can omit `-ErrorAction Ignore`).
- To test if an environment variable whose name is stored in variable `${strAllowGPU_Group}` is defined, use:
  `Test-Variable Env:${strAllowGPU_Group}`
  (same as: `Test-Variable Env:$strAllowGPU_Group` and
  `Test-Variable "Env:$strAllowGPU_Group"`)

---

###### Background information:

- ***Fundamentally*, what follows `$` must be a *verbatim* identifier, optionally prefixed by a *verbatim* namespace**.

  - That is, you cannot *indirectly* refer to a variable, via its name being stored in *another* variable with this syntax.
  - Therefore, **`$env:${strAllowGPU_Group}` *cannot* work**, given that what follows `env:` must be a *verbatim* environment-variable name.
- As for the ***incidental* aspect** of using **`{...}` around a variable name** in a PowerShell variable reference:

  - **`{...}` is only *necessary* if**:

    - (a) if the name contains *unusual characters*;<sup>[1]</sup> e.g.:

      - `${a.b} = 'foo'; ${a.b}` - unusual variable name `a.b` *requires* enclosure in `{...}`
    - (b) inside an [expandable (double-quoted) string (`"..."`)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Quoting_Rules#double-quoted-strings), if the characters following the variable name in the string would otherwise be mistaken for being part of the variable name; e.g.:

      - `$var='foo'; "A ${var}l and his money are soon parted."` - without `{...}`, PowerShell would try to reference a variable named `varl`
  - However, **you're free to *always* use `{...}`**:

    - `$foo_bar = 'baz'; ${foo_bar}` - `$foo_bar` is sufficient, but `${foo_bar}` works too.
  - If you do use `{...}`, it **must enclose *both* the *namespace prefix*<sup>[2]</sup> (if present) and the variable name**:

    - E.g., `$env:HOME` is the same as `${env:HOME}`
    - By contrast, <del>`$env:{HOME}`</del> is *broken syntax*.

---

###### Solutions:

To use ***variable indirection* with environment variables**, i.e. to access them via their name being stored in *another variable*, you must **use *cmdlets that access the [`Env:` drive](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Environment_Provider)***:

- To *test* if an environment variable whose name is stored in `$strAllowGPU_Group` (aka `${strAllowGPU_Group}`) exists, use the following:

  ```bash
  Test-Path Env:$strAllowGPU_Group
  ```

  - Note: This assumes that `$strAllowGPU_Group` has a *non-empty value*; if `$strAllowGPU_Group` evaluates to `$null` (including when no such variable is defined) or the *empty string*, the command invariably returns `$true`.
- To *get the value of* the environment variable whose name is stored in variable `$strAllowGPU_Group`:

  ```bash
  Get-Content -ErrorAction Ignore Env:$strAllowGPU_Group
  ```
- To *set the value of* the environment variable whose name is stored in variable `$strAllowGPU_Group`:

  ```bash
  Set-Content Env:$strAllowGPU_Group 'new value'
  ```

Note:

- To do the same thing for ***regular* variables**, use the **[`Variable:` drive](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Variable_Provider)**; for setting and getting variable values indirectly, you **may also use** the **[`Get-Variable`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/get-variable)** and **[`Set-Variable`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/set-variable)**.

---

<sup>[1] For the exact rules, see the relevant section of the conceptual "about_Variables" help topic, [Variable Names that Include Special Characters](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Variables#variable-names-that-include-special-characters)</sup>

<sup>[2] For more information about PowerShell's *namespace variable notation*, see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55036515/45375).</sup>