# Is there a way to add click events to multiple buttons in a loop using Powershell and WPF?

Tags: wpf, powershell

I have several buttons that perform the same function on different list boxes (Sort them, or open an Out-GridView to search them).  I would like to make my code more "DRY" by adding click events to the buttons in a loop.  However, when I try it, all of the buttons only perform the function intended for the final button in the loop.

Here is the code I have:

```
$gui.btnNewUserGroupsSort.Add_Click({
    SortListbox -listboxName "lsbNewUserGroups"
})

$gui.btnNewUserHuntGroupsSort.Add_Click({
    SortListbox -listboxName "lsbNewUserHuntGroups"
})

$gui.btnAvailableGroupsSort.Add_Click({
    SortListbox -listboxName "lsbAvailableGroups"
})

$gui.btnAvailableHuntGroupsSort.Add_Click({
    SortListbox -listboxName "lsbAvailableHuntGroups"
})
```

Here is the code that I would LIKE to be using if there is a solution:

```
$sortCategories = @(
    "NewUserGroups",
    "NewUserHuntGroups",
    "AvailableGroups",
    "AvailableHuntGroups"
)

Foreach ($sortCategory in $sortCategories) {
    $button = "btn$($sortCategory)Sort"
    $listbox = "lsb$($sortCategory)"
    $gui.$button.Add_Click({
        SortListbox -listboxName $listbox
    })
}
```

I have tried adding a GetNewClosure() method to the click event, but when I do, I can no longer call the SortListbox function, because of the scope issue (I think).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- What you need is a *closure* that captures the then-current value of the `$listbox` *variable* in each iteration.
- However, in order to also make the `SortListBox` *function* available to the closure, you must store it *in the form of a variable* too, which you can do with [namespace variable notation](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55036515/45375) (`$function:SortListBox`)

Therefore:

```bash
# ...
# Capture the SortListbox function (body) *as a variable*.
$sortListboxFunc = $function:SortListbox
foreach ($sortCategory in $sortCategories) {
    $button = "btn${sortCategory}Sort"
    $listbox = "lsb${sortCategory}"
    # Call .GetNewClosure() on the script block to create a closure,
    # and invoke the function via the $sortListboxFunc variable,
    # using &, the call operator.
    $gui.$button.Add_Click({
        & $sortListboxFunc -listboxName $listbox
    }.GetNewClosure())
}
```

Note:

- **[`.GetNewClosure()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/System.Management.Automation.ScriptBlock.GetNewClosure)** captures **copies of the caller's *local variables* - and *nothing else***; that is, neither local functions nor aliases are copied.
- **The resulting [script block](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Script_Blocks) runs in a [*dynamic module*](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/new-module)**, which has the following **implications**:

  - Whatever other variables the calling scope may see from *ancestral* scope as well as any function or alias definitions local to the caller's scope or seen via ancestral scopes -  due to PowerShell's *dynamic scoping* - are only visible if they were defined in the *global* scope, which is the only scope that (dynamic) modules are connected to.
  - Commands from *globally* imported (persisted) [modules](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Modules) *are* visible to the dynamic module:

    - Global import is what [`Import-Module`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/import-module) and module *auto-loading* do *by default*.
    - By contrast, commands from a module imported with `Import-Module -Scope Local` in the caller's scope or any of its ancestral scope other than the global one are *not* visible (unless the caller is itself in the global scope).
  - Any *strict-mode setting* (e.g., [`Set-StrictMode`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/set-strictmode) `-Version 1`) is *never* seen by the dynamic module; that is, by default it behaves as if `Set-StrictMode -Off` were in effect.

    - For a discussion of the design rationale behind this, see [GitHub issue #20812](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/20812)

Comment: I have tried the GetNewClosure(), but when I do, I can no longer call my SortListbox function for some reason.  As I mentioned above, I am assuming it's a scope issue.  Am I missing something?

Comment: @Mike, sorry, I missed that. Please see my update, which clarifies the constraints when using `.GetNewClosure()`. If you explain in detail where your function is defined, we may find a solution.

Comment: Rather than using a global scope, I went ahead and copied the function into the loop.  It seems to be working now.  Thank you for your help!

Comment: Glad to hear it, @Mike, but please note that my explanation wasn't quite correct: Please see my update, which not only provides a (hopefully now) correct explanation, but a solution that doesn't require copying the function into the script block.